# Notepad++ или IDE для изучения Java?

Tags: java, ide

Посоветуйте, как лучше поступить для изучения java. Использовать IDE или лучше использовать notepad++ с подключенным компилятором для того, чтобы научиться программировать на java?

Answer (score 5):

Для обучения notepad + компилятор. Так более правильно (понимание приходит - что куда и зачем).

Comment: можно подкинуть инструкцию как настроить notepad++ с компилятором

Answer (score 4):

Есть классные IDE: IDEA(есть Community редакция),Eclipse, NetBeans.
Из редакторов: jEdit, Editra, Geany и еще тьма, хоть тот же NotePad++.

Я бы посоветовал попробовать все и остановиться на понравившемся продукте.
Для обучения и FARа достаточно, там и редактор есть и командная строчка под рукой. Ну а если хотите подсветку и плюшки, то берите IDE или удобный редактор.

Answer (score 4):

Пока идет освоение, набивание руки и заучивание конструкций языка, гораздо полезнее глядеть не в подсказки IDE(которая и возвращаемое значение скастует, и импорты пропишет, и final расставит, где надо, и по Ctrl+Space подскажет, что набирать), а в вывод компилятора в командной строке.

Плюсы:

- быстрее столкнетесь с типовыми ошибками и их решением
- быстрее выучите API без подсказок среды разработки
- будете понимать, что делает IDE при нажатии на кнопку "Run"
- меньше будет вопросов на форумах про NPE и Classpath

Как понимание процесса появится - можно и IDE лезть.

То же самое касается и вспомогательных инструментов: ant, maven, VCS-ы. Важно сначала научиться пользоваться ими из консоли и понять как они работают, а уж после этого ставить плагины для IDE и жать кнопки.

ЗЫ. И не "подключайте" компилятор java к notepad++. Вызывайте его руками из командной строки.

Comment: про ант и прочее мысль хорошая конечно.

Answer (score 3):

Разработанные под Java IDE — очевидное достоинство языка, я ни для каких других языков не чувствовал такого комфорта разработки.
**IntelliJ IDEA** — шикарнейший продукт, всячески рекомендую.
**Eclipse** — отличная IDE, я бы помимо всего прочего отметил её универсальность, под практически все языки есть плагины, добавляющие поддержку и нужню функциональность.
Я, например, верстал tex-странички в этой IDE.
C **NetBeans** не работал, но об ней также хорошо отзываются люди.

Но первых несколько программ советую вам написать и позапускать с помощью консоли. Так придёт понимание хотя бы такой хитрой штуки, как classpath. Ну, если быть точнее, там интересней, например, скомпилировать и запустить программу, использующую парочку библиотек в Jar'никах.

Comment: Самое крутое, что я видел - это NetBeans.

Comment: Попробуйте Идею и будет с чем сравнить. А так дело вкуса конечно :)

Answer (score 3):

Лучше используйте обычный NetBeans без всяких дополнительных плагинов и плюшек. Вполне достаточно Вам будет. Всё-таки писать в блокноте по сути, не совсем айс, вот такое имхо.

Answer (score 2):

Использовать IDE. Могу посоветовать Eclipse.